# Where is my coding wrong and how is the correct coding

Tags: laravel

> ErrorException (E_WARNING) in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given

```
if (
    (in_array('open', $auction_status)
    || in_array('new', $auction_status))
    && !in_array('closed', $auction_status)
) {
    $cond[] = ['auctions.start_date', '<=', NOW()];
    $cond[] = ['auctions.end_date', '>=', NOW()];
```

Comment: Hi, the error is self-explanatory. You need to check `$auction_status`. `var_dump($auction_status)`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `$auction_status` is not an array. You could try

```
if (
    in_array($auction_status, ['open', 'new'])
    && $auction_status !== 'closed'
) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: how to make auction status an array